# How to display an alert when network request fails?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React's Context Api in my Project
Below is my code

```
const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'error':
      return {...state, ...{errorMessage: action.payload}, ...{loading: false}};
    case 'signUp':
      return {...state, ...{data: action.payload}, ...{loading: false}};
    case 'signIn':
      return;
    case 'inProgress':
      return {...state, ...{loading: true}};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const signUp = dispatch => {
  return async ({email, password}) => {
    try {
      dispatch({type: 'inProgress'});
      //do network request
      dispatch({type: 'signUp', payload: response.data});
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'error',
        payload: 'Something went wrong',
      });
      Alert.alert('Something went wrong');
    }
  };
};
```

I am calling the Alert after dispatch in catch clause which never gets called.
Even if I write Alert statement before dispatch, it automatically gets close and I still see my progress bar

My ProgressBar code is as follows

```
{state.loading ? <ProgressBar /> : null}
```

Comment: Change the status of loading to false.

Comment: @hongdevelop I have change the status of loading to false in case of error, please have a look at the code

Comment: Can you check if your state is being changed correctly? You could use Redux devtools on chrome to verify if state change is applied